# Beautifulsoup - nextSibling

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the content "My home address" using the following but got the AttributeError:

```
address = soup.find(text="Address:")
print address.nextSibling
```

This is my HTML:

```
<td><b>Address:</b></td>
<td>My home address</td>
```

What is a good way to navigate down `td` tag and pull the content?

Answer (score 111):

The problem is that you have found a `NavigableString`, not the `<td>`. Also `nextSibling` will find the next `NavigableString` *or* `Tag` so even if you had the `<td>` it wouldn't work the way you expect.

This is what you want:

```
address = soup.find(text="Address:")
b_tag = address.parent
td_tag = b_tag.parent
next_td_tag = td_tag.findNext('td')
print next_td_tag.contents[0]
```

Or more concise:

```
print soup.find(text="Address:").parent.parent.findNext('td').contents[0]
```

Actually you could just do

```
print soup.find(text="Address:").findNext('td').contents[0]
```

Since `findNext` just calls `next` over and over again, and `next` finds the next element *as parsed* repeatedly until it matches.

Answer (score 21):

Try this if you use bs4:

```
print soup.find(string="Address:").find_next('td').contents[0]
```

Answer (score 16):

I don't know if this was possible in 2011 but in 2021 I'd recommend you to do it using `find_next_sibling()` like this:

```py
address = soup.find(text="Address:")
b = address.parent
address_td = b.parent
target_td = address_td.find_next_sibling('td')
```

The accepted answer works in your case but it would not work if you had something like:

```html
<div>
  <div><b>Address:</b><div>THE PROBLEM</div></div>
  <div>target</div>
</div>
```

You'd end up with `<div>THE PROBLEM</div>` instead of `<div>target</div>`.

Comment: The 'text' argument for find() is deprecated.  Use 'string' instead of 'text'. See docs: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id11

Answer (score 3):

You can use `findChildren` pretty easily to iterate over the td's in a table, assuming it's in a table. You could find the table first, ideally:

```
table = soup.find('table')
>>> for td in table.findChildren('td'):
...:     print td.text
...:     
...:     
Address:
My home address
```

Or you could search for address, and get the table container:

```
>>> import re
>>> search = re.compile('Address')
>>> table = soup.find(text=search).parent.parent.parent
```

Comment: There're a lot of tables so finding tables then td don't look like a good choice.