# Not getting desired text from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
            <h3 class="jd_header3 text" style="font-size: 12px;">
               Shift Pattern:
              </h3>
              <ul class="jd_NoBulletinRight">
               <li style="font-size:11px;">
                <span class="text">
                 No Shift
                </span>
               </li>
              </ul>
              <h3 class="jd_header3 text" style="align:left;font-size:12px;">
               Salary:
              </h3>
              <ul class="jd_NoBulletinRight">
               <li>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                 <tbody>
                  <tr>
                   <td align="left" style="word-wrap: break-word;font-size: 11px;" valign="top">
                    <span class="text">
                     S$3,500.00
                     <span class="text">
                      -
                     </span>
                     S$5,400.00
                    </span>
                   </td>
                  </tr>
                 </tbody>
                </table>
               </li>
              </ul>
```

This is a part of my BeautifulSoup tree. I wish to get the salary range S$3500 - S$5400. Following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999747/beautifulsoup-nextsibling) I use the following code:

```
salary = bsObj.find(text="Salary:").parent.nextSibling.find("td").get_text()
print(salary)
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

But when I simply print out the integer:

```
salary = bsObj.find(text="Salary:").parent.nextSibling.find("td")
print(salary)
```

I get:

```
-1
```

Which is not what I want. I have used Selenium to obtain the page, so any javascript is already loaded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, however I don't think your code can get your expect output:

```
>>> bsObj.find('td', {'align': "left"}).text
'\n\n                     S$3,500.00\n                     \n                      -\n                     \n                     S$5,400.00
\n                    \n'

>>> ' '.join(bsObj.find('td', {'align': "left"}).text.split())
'S$3,500.00 - S$5,400.00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this "get_text" attribute, but with BeautifulSoup, I rely heavily on `.text` as shown below. Is this what you're looking for?

```
s = '''<html here>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
bsObj = soup.findAll('td')
for i in bsObj:
    print(i.text)

>>> 


                     S$3,500.00

                      -

                     S$5,400.00
```