# Using BeautifulSoup with multiple tags with the same name

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the below html

```
<g class="1581 sqw_sv5" style="cursor: pointer;">
 <path d="M397.696,126.554C397.696,126.554,404.57504,140.2417375,404.57504,140.2417375" stroke="#ffffff" style="stroke-width: 3.6; stroke-opacity: 0.5; stroke-linecap: round; fill-opacity: 0;">
 </path>
 <path d="M397.696,126.554C397.696,126.554,404.57504,140.2417375,404.57504,140.2417375" stroke="#f95a0b" style="stroke-width: 1.2; stroke-linecap: round; fill-opacity: 0;">
 </path>
```

I need to obtain the value of the 'stroke' in the second *path*. My current code is only pulling the value from the first *path*.

I am currently using

```
shots = soup.find_all('g')
for shot in shots:
    print(shot.path['stroke'])
```

which returns #ffffff. I need it to return #f95a0b

Comment: Is it always the second path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution to your question.  My issue with my answer is that it may be overly specific.  This will only work if the value of `style` is always `"stroke-width: 1.2; stroke-linecap: round; fill-opacity: 0;"` and if only one such `path` element is present in the entire document.

The idea behind this solution is to quickly narrow down the elements by looking for what's unique to the desired element containing the desired attribute.

```
`
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """"<g class="1581 sqw_sv5" style="cursor: pointer;">
 <path d="M397.696,126.554C397.696,126.554,404.57504,140.2417375,404.57504,140.2417375" stroke="#ffffff" style="stroke-width: 3.6; stroke-opacity: 0.5; stroke-linecap: round; fill-opacity: 0;">
 </path>
 <path d="M397.696,126.554C397.696,126.554,404.57504,140.2417375,404.57504,140.2417375" stroke="#f95a0b" style="stroke-width: 1.2; stroke-linecap: round; fill-opacity: 0;">
 </path>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
# get the desired 'path' element using the 'style' that identifies it
desired_element =  soup.find("path", {"style" : "stroke-width: 1.2; stroke-linecap: round; fill-opacity: 0;"})
# get the attribute value from the extracted element
desired_attribute = desired_element["stroke"]
print (desired_attribute)
# prints #f95a0b
`
```

If this approach is a no go, then you may have to use BeautifulSoups's `next_sibling` or `findNext` methods. Basically look for the first path element, which you are currently accomplishing with your code, then 'jump' from there to the next path element, which contains what you need.

findNext: [Beautifulsoup - nextSibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999747/beautifulsoup-nextsibling)

next_sibling: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't use your first suggestion, but next_sibling worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use find_all to first find all the *path's* and then extract the last one:

```
h = """<g class="1581 sqw_sv5" style="cursor: pointer;">
 <path d="M397.696,126.554C397.696,126.554,404.57504,140.2417375,404.57504,140.2417375" stroke="#ffffff" style="stroke-width: 3.6; stroke-opacity: 0.5; stroke-linecap: round; fill-opacity: 0;">
 </path>
 <path d="M397.696,126.554C397.696,126.554,404.57504,140.2417375,404.57504,140.2417375" stroke="#f95a0b" style="stroke-width: 1.2; stroke-linecap: round; fill-opacity: 0;">
 </path>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
shots = soup.find_all('g')
for shot in shots:
    print(shot.find_all("path", stroke=True)[-1]["stroke"]
```

Using `shot.path['stroke']` is equivalent to using `shot.find("path")['stroke']` which would only return the first path.

Or using *nth-of-type* may also work depending on the structure of the html:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
shots = soup.find_all('g')
for shot in shots:
    print(shot.select_one("path:nth-of-type(2)")["stroke"])
```